# I'd like to change the way the date is formatted in the body of my email to show just month and date using Google's script

Tags: html

I'd like to change the way the date is formatted in the body of my email to show just month and date using Google's script

```
var email_body = '<html><body> Hey Byro <br> <br> Please see your daily checklist below: <br> <br> <table style = border-collapse:collapse; border = 1 cellpadding = 5><tr>';
      for (var row=0;row<data.length;++row){
        for (var col = 0; col<data[0].length;++col)
        {
          if (row==0)
          {email_body+='<th>'+data[row][col]+'</th>'}
          else{
            email_body+='<td>'+data[row][col]+'</td>'
          }
        }
        email_body+='</tr><tr>'
      }
      email_body += '</tr></table><br><br> Thank You </body></html>'
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipiants,subject,"",{htmlBody:email_body})
```

Comment: Only you can answer this I think. Where is this date coming from, and how is it formatted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no date in your template/body of the email.

You can use a standard JS way to get the current date - below I used the `new Date().toLocaleDateString()` method and I slightly modified the function to cover my own test needs, but the logic stays the same.

```
function sendDailyTasksReminder() {
  
  var email_body = '<html><body> Hey Byro <br> <br> Please see your daily (<b>' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '</b>) checklist below: <br> <br> <table style = border-collapse:collapse; border = 1 cellpadding = 5><tr>';

  let checkList = ["Air Filter", "Transmission Fluid", "Replace Spark Plugs"];

  checkList.forEach((item, index)=>{
    if(index == 0){
      email_body+='<th>'+'#'+'</th>'
      email_body+='<th>'+'Task'+'</th>'
      email_body+='</tr><tr>'
    }
    email_body+='<td>'+index+'</td>'
    email_body+='<td>'+item+'</td>'
    email_body+='</tr><tr>'
  })

  email_body += '</tr></table><br><br> Thank You </body></html>'

  MailApp.sendEmail("example@email.com","Test Email Template","",{htmlBody:email_body});
}
```

[image]

To get the date excluding the year:

```
  let dd = new Date()
  month = dd.getMonth() + 1;
  day = dd.getDate();
```

And then replace in the template with:

```
Please see your daily (<b>' + day+'/'+month + '</b>) checklist below ...
```